# Using the MDX query builder in Visual Studio, how can I filter the parameters to choose '1/1/2010' - last month?

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, ssas, mdx, query-builder

I have been trying to pass dynamic date parameters in SSRS's Visual Studio using SSAS and the Query Designer. I am trying to get my MDX query to pull from '1/1/2010' to last month using the CalendarMonth field. Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Full Case Quantity]
     ,[Measures].[Total]
     ,[Measures].[Verified Total]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [PA Product].[PA Description].[PA Description].ALLMEMBERS*
        [PA Product].[PA Product ID].[PA Product ID].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Time].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].ALLMEMBERS*
        [PA Product].[PA Uom].[PA Uom].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Distributor].[Dist Name].[Dist Name].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Time].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].ALLMEMBERS*
        [Time].[Month Number Of Year].[Month Number Of Year].ALLMEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[Concept OG].[Is Concept Display].&[1]} ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {[Concept].[Concept ID].&[6501]} ON COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        NULL : StrToMember(@ToTimeCalendarMonth,CONSTRAINED) ON COLUMNS
      FROM [Management]
    )
  )
)
WHERE 
  (
    [Concept].[Concept ID].&[6501]
   ,[Concept OG].[Is Concept Display].&[1]
  )
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,FONT_NAME
 ,FONT_SIZE
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
```

Comment: It looks ok - what is the problem? This looks like valid `mdx` ... `NULL : StrToMember(@ToTimeCalendarMonth,CONSTRAINED)`

Comment: Do you need to replace null with your date member for 1/1/2010 in the `NULL : StrToMember(@ToTimeCalendarMonth,CONSTRAINED)`? Or are you asking how to calculate the last month based on the current date?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is so need to do some digging!

If you run the following in `SSMS` what is returned? You will need to replace `@ToTimeCalendarMonth` with whatever your parameter is passing in:

```
SELECT 
    {} on 0,
    NULL : StrToMember(@ToTimeCalendarMonth,CONSTRAINED) ON 1
FROM [Management]
```

The parameter will need to be something like this ... I don't know how the members in your cube look so this is a guess:

```
[Time].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].[200604]
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this: `FROM ( SELECT ( null : [Time].[Calendar Month].DefaultMember.Lag(-1) ) ON COLUMNS` That way I set the range between my default start date and an equivalent MDX statement for DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())